# RelativeLayout not expanding to fill parent when views are added to parent

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) inside a [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) as the code below shows

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                               xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                               android:orientation="vertical"
                                               android:padding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/clickBox"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/PaleBlack"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_widthPercent="35%">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleX="0.8"
            android:scaleY="0.8"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_open"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

It gives a look like shown below, which is good
[image]

But if I then programatically add a TextView to the `PercentRelativeLayout`, the `RelativeLayout` does not expand filling the parent vertically `PercentRelativeLayout`, which then results as shown below

[image]

How can I fix this so the `RelativeLayout` fills the parent in its height?

Comment: Isn't it clear? The RelativeLayout **does** expand (well, at least, if you set `android:layout_width="match_parent"`). The ImageView **does not**.

Comment: @ModularSynth No it does not, I put a black background to make sure and it does not expand

Comment: @TimCastelijns There is no second XML unfortunately. The views are added dynamically via code after the Layout has been drawn

Comment: I said:  **if you set `android:layout_width="match_parent"`**

Comment: @ModularSynth I missed that, sorry. However, I do not want it to match parent on its width, I want to keep the same width.

Comment: The two images don't match with the layout. There's an extra TextView in one of them! And I don't get why there's an extra RelativeLayout, too.

Comment: As I said, the second image shows an example of how it looks when a specific TextView has been added programatically via code. @ModularSynth

Comment: It's there because I later make it clickable, I wanted it bigger than the ImageView. Sure I could set a size on the ImageView as well, the second RelativeLayout might be redundant. @ModularSynth

Comment: The ImageView is redundant anyway, since you can put it inside the TextView, as a **compound drawable**.

Comment: When I removed the redundant RelativeLayout and put 35% width on the ImageView and height to match_parent, it worked. I did not know about the compound drawable, I will look into that. Thanks for your help @ModularSynth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `PercentRelativeLayout` is deprecated, you could consider switching to a `ConstraintLayout` solution with a layout like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.30" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You could add a second guideline and anchor the `TextView` that you are generating to the guideline and to the parent just as I did to the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Did not know you could use percentages in ConstraintLayouts. I'm gonna look into this and eventually convert my PercentRelativeLayouts to Constraints. Cheers